# NSubstitute returning NullReferenceException when Using ForPartsOf and mocking an Async Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit, nsubstitute

I have two methods:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual async Task MethodOne(MyModel myModel)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);

        throw new Exception("Test");
    }

    public async Task MethodTwo()
    {
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        await MethodOne(myModel);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what MyModel is, but it does matter that it's a parameter.

And the test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test6()
{
    // Arrange
    MyClass myClass = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();
    myClass.When(async a => await a.MethodOne(Arg.Any<MyModel>())).DoNotCallBase();

    // Act 
    await myClass.MethodTwo();

    // Assert

}
```

The test gives a `NullReferenceException` when the line:

```
myClass.When(async a => await a.MethodOne(Arg.Any<MyModel>())).DoNotCallBase();
```

My guess is that it is, in some way, trying to resolve `MyModel`; however, the same test works, when performed on a synchronous method, or one without a complex parameter.

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs in this way?

Comment: 1)Do not await the setup 2)overridden method needs to return a Task to allow async to flow to completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not await the setup
2. overridden method needs to return a `Task` to allow async to flow to completion when invoked in test.

That means the setup needs to be rewritten

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test6() {
    // Arrange
    var myClass = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>();
    myClass.MethodOne(Arg.Any<MyModel>()).Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));

    // Act 
    await myClass.MethodTwo();

    // Assert
    //...
}
```

Comment: That stops the issue from happening - but doesn't answer my question as to why this occurs

Comment: Because in awaiting the setup it is actually trying to invoke the method which would need to compile the expression and thus need to get the argument passed in, which would be null as `Arg.*` does not give an actual object.

Comment: Yes - of course it is.  Strange how you can look at something for ages and not see the obvious.  Thanks for your help